# IE: vertical scrollbar appears if horizontal scrollbar shown

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scrollbar, overlap

i've got an issue with scrollbars showing up in Internet Explorer.
I've got a div of which it's content can be wider than the div itself, so a horizontal scollbar appears. The horizontal scrollbar is fine, but Internet Explorer also shows a vertical scrollbar if a horizontal one is shown. I suppose that's because IE let's the horizontal scrollbar overlap some content wherefore the vertical one is shown.
Now my question is if there is some trick to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from overlapping the content, thus appearing under the content, so a vertical scrollbar doesn't appear? Even when i'm adding some padding-bottom the scrollbar seems to keep overlapping the div's content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Overflow-y:hidden; (vertical scroll bar)
```

bit of a hack but works

Comment: CSS property names are lower-case. Also, `overflow-y` is a regular CSS property, not a hack at all.

Comment: Doesnt work if you have overflow-x: auto; and overflow-y:hidden; then the horizontal scroll bar will correctly still appear when necessary but the horizontal scrollbar will take up space needed by the content and now there is also no vertical scrollbar to see the overlapped content. We need some way to have IE allocate extra space for the content (padding and margins dont seem to do it)